# Use of castle windsor means ISession sometimes disposed more than once

Tags: nhibernate, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

All my repository interfaces (i.e. implemented by classes for persisting entities to the database) have a dependency on an interface called `IUnitOfWork`. The repository classes and the `IUnitOfWork` are handled by Castle Windsor and have a lifestyle of `PerWebRequest`.

The `Repository<T>` implementation (which is extended by all repositories) looks like this:

```
public abstract class Repository<T> where T : Entity
{
  protected IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

  internal Repository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
  {
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
  }

  public T Load(int id)
  {
    T t;
    t = _unitOfWork.Load<T>(id);
    return t;
  }

  public virtual void Save(T t)
  {
    _unitOfWork.Save(t);
  }

  public virtual void Delete(T t)
  {
    _unitOfWork.Delete(t);
  }

  public IQueryable<T> All
  {
    get { return _unitOfWork.GetList<T>(); }
  }
}
```

The class which implements `IUnitOfWork` uses NHibernate (it contains an `ISession`) and has a `Dispose` method like this:

```
public void Dispose()
{
  _session.Flush();
  _session.Dispose();
}
```

Thus, the saving of an entity follows the following steps:

1. Repository retrieved from DI container (with `IUnitOfWork` injected in)
2. Entity loaded through repository's `Load` method
3. Entity modified
4. Entity saved through repository's `Save` method
5. Repository and `IUnitOfWork` disposed by DI container at end of web request - changes flushed to database

My problem is that I am occasionally getting the '**Session is closed! Object name: 'ISession**' error from NHibernate.

So far as I can see, the only place the `ISession` is disposed is when the `IUnitOfWork`'s `Dispose()` method is called, which is only called by the DI container.

Can anyone think of any other reason I could be getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

That probably happens when you have an exception somewhere, or you're trying to call `Dispose` yourself in the code somewhere.

Windsor guarantees that the code will be only executed once.

As a sidenote - why do you need the `IUnitOfWork`? It doesn't add any value.

Comment: Ah, hi Krzysztof. Thanks as ever for your input. I definitely never explicitly Dispose the IUnitOfWork anywhere else. I will look into the exception option.

Comment: As for your question, once upon a time it seemed like a good idea to hide my NHibernate DAL behind a set of interfaces to allow it to be swapped out. It actually works quite well - how would I get Windsor to inject ISession instances if they're not hidden behind an interface?

Comment: Re using `ISession` directly. Easily - there are tons of examples on the web including official WIndsor tutorial. Why - I agree with @ayende on this http://tv.devexpress.com/#DallasOrenEini